# Custom functions in __init__.py cause Django Apps Aren't Installed Yet Error

Tags: python, django

I have a setup like the following

```
    Tasks
      |__ __init__.py
      |__ a.py
      |__ b.py
      |__ c.py
         ...
```

Inside the __init__.py file,

```
    from .a import custom1, custom2
    from .b import custom3, custom4
```

I wrote a function within Tasks which requires Tasks to be added as an INSTALLED_APP.

The custom functions however raise django.core.exceptions.AppRegistryNotReady: "Apps aren't loaded yet.".

The traceback leads to a point where one of the custom functions try to import

`from django.contrib.auth.models import User`.

Why does this happen, and is there a way to fix this error WITHOUT moving the custom functions out of the __init__.py file?

Comment: Can you share the full traceback? That error usually occurs when you attempt to access models before they have been loaded, what is this function doing?

Comment: You probably want to use AppConfig and import in ready method instead. But this is too little of info to understand what exactly you are importing

Comment: Full traceback leads to some function trying to use django.auth User model, but I'm not sure what the order of django initialization is that prevents this from happening..

Comment: Add the traceback to the question, you are doing something with a model before all apps have been loaded

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Order of Django initialization is well [documented](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/applications/#how-applications-are-loaded)

> 1.) First Django imports each item in INSTALLED_APPS.
>
> **At this stage, your code shouldn’t import any models!**

...

> 3.)Finally Django runs the `ready()` method of each application configuration.

And futher as [documented](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/applications/#django.apps.AppConfig.ready) in `AppConfig.ready()`

> Subclasses can override this method to perform initialization tasks
> such as registering signals. It is called as soon as the registry is
> fully populated.
>
> ```
> class RockNRollConfig(AppConfig):
> # ...
>
>     def ready(self):
>         # importing model classes
>         from .models import MyModel  # or...
>         MyModel = self.get_model('MyModel')
>
>         # registering signals with the model's string label
>         pre_save.connect(receiver, sender='app_label.MyModel')
> ```

---

You might consider use of [`get_model`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/applications/#django.apps.apps.get_model) inside of your function that would replace import with `require_ready` false

But I am not certain it would work depending on your use case